# Use 'view more' button to enhance information on each table row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a pretty simple html table, there are lots of information i want to add for each row but i cant display everything when the page is loaded because it is going to make everything very clumsy. So i want to add a view more button in another column for each of the row.

I have already tried writing a JavaScript code but its not working as i want. What i want is:

1. The row should be completely invisible until i click the view more (i tried putting the  tags inside the div but it messed everything up by putting the row outside the table entirely).
2. I want the code to work for all the rows so i don't have to write separate codes for each row.
3. I want the extended information for a row to be invisible whenever i try to view more for another row.
4. If possible, i would like a simple animation for showing the extended animation.

**Below is my HTML code:**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td><a href="#" id="example-show" class="showLink" onclick="showHide('example');return false;" class="btn bN-btn-base bN-btn-small">View More</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <div id="example" class="more">
                <p>John Doe is a man</p>
                <p style="text-align:right;"><a href="#" id="example-hide" class="hideLink" onclick="showHide('example');return false;">Hide this content.</a></p>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jane</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td><a href="#" id="example-show" class="showLink" onclick="showHide('example');return false;" class="btn bN-btn-base bN-btn-small">View More</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <div id="example" class="more">
                <p>Jane Doe is a woman</p>
                <p style="text-align:right;"><a href="#" id="example-hide" class="hideLink" onclick="showHide('example');return false;">Hide this content.</a></p>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Below is my CSS:**

```
<style type="text/css">
   .more {
      display: none;
   }
   a.showLink, a.hideLink {
      text-decoration: none;
      color: #36f;
      padding-left: 8px;
      background: transparent url(down.gif) no-repeat left; 
   }
   a.hideLink {
      background: transparent url(up.gif) no-repeat left;
   }
   a.showLink:hover, a.hideLink:hover {
      border-bottom: 1px dotted #36f; 
   }
</style>
```

**Below is my Javascript:**

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function showHide(shID) {
   if (document.getElementById(shID)) {
      if (document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display != 'none') {
         document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display = 'none';
         document.getElementById(shID).style.display = 'block';
      }
      else {
         document.getElementById(shID+'-show').style.display = 'inline';
         document.getElementById(shID).style.display = 'none';
      }
   }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged jQuery, I'm assuming you're willing to use it, so here's an example of a fix with jQuery:

**EDIT: The html has changed, the second row failed to work due to the ID selector**

**HTML**

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Firstname</th>
        <th>Lastname</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>John</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td><a href="#" id="example-show" class="showLink" onclick="showHide('example');return false;" class="btn bN-btn-base bN-btn-small">View More</a></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
            <div id="example" class="more">
                <p>John Doe is a man</p>
                <p style="text-align:right;"><a href="#" id="example-hide" class="hideLink" onclick="showHide('example');return false;">Hide this content.</a></p>
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Jane</td>
        <td>Doe</td>
        <td><a href="#" id="example-show" class="showLink" onclick="showHide('exampleFemale');return false;" class="btn bN-btn-base bN-btn-small">View More</a></td><!-- Note the change in the showHide() function -->
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3">
        <div id="exampleFemale" class="more"><!-- Note the change in the ID -->
                <p>Jane Doe is a woman</p>
                <p style="text-align:right;"><a href="#" id="example-hide" class="hideLink" onclick="showHide('exampleFemale');return false;">Hide this content.</a></p><!-- Note the change in the showHide() function -->
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Javascript**

```
function showHide(shID) {
    if ($('#' + shID)) {
      if ($('#' + shID+'-show').css('display') != 'none') {
       $('#' + shID+'-show').css({'display':'none'});
       $('#' + shID).css({'display':'block'});
      }
   }
   else {
       $('#' + shID+'-show').css({'display':'inline'});
       $('#' + shID).css({'display':'none'});
   }
}
```

Note the changes inthe Javascript -> jQuery where there used to be `document.getElementById(shID+'-show')` is now `$('#' + shID+'-show')` and where there used to be `.style.display = 'none';` is now `.css({'display':'none'});`

**Don't forget to include jQuery**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Hope this helps!